# Cucumber: Found scenario when expecting one of: comment, feature, tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber

I am trying to run a cucmber test but i got a strange error! working with `gem 'cucumber-rails', '1.0.6'`

```
features/hidden_links.feature: Parse error at features/hidden_links.feature:1. Found scenario when expecting one of: comment, feature, tag. (Current state: root). (Gherkin::Parser::ParseError)
```

hidden_links.feature

```
Scenario: Edit project link is hidden for non-signed-in users
  Given I am on the homepage
  When I follow "TextMate 2"
  Then I should not see the "Edit Project" link

Scenario: Edit project link is hidden for signed-in user
  Given I am signed in as "user@ticketee.com"
  When I follow "TextMate 2"
  Then I should not see the "Edit Project" link

Scenario: Edit project link is shown to admin
  Given I am signed in as "admin@ticketee.com"
  When I follow "TextMate 2"
  Then I should see the "Edit Proeject" link

Scenario: Delete project link is hidden for non-signed-in users
  Given I am on the homepage
  When I follow "TextMate 2"
  Then I should not see the "Delete Project" link

Scenario: Delete project link is hidden for signed-in users
  Given I am signed in as "user@ticketee.com"
  When I follow "TextMate 2"
  Then I should not see the "Delete Project" link

Scenario: Delete project link is shown to admins
  Given I am signed in as "admin@ticketee.com"
  When I follow "TextMate 2"
  Then I should see the "Delete Project" link
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Feature file [should start from Feature keyword, not from Scenario](http://cukes.info/gherkin.html).

```
Feature: Hidden links
```